# Issue with Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am trying the demo for angular material tool bar. The default code for js is not having a any dependent modules. The code looks like below

```
angular.module('MyApp')

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

But if I add a new module or empty square braces like below, its not working

```
angular.module('MyApp',[])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

If you remove it, its working. How can i add a module without affecting the material design ?

The link to plunker is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/hvDdJFDV8CwFPD7Dj3Uu?p=preview)

Comment: Do you not need the dependencies in your [], such as [ngMaterial, ...]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add ngMaterial to your angular app like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial']);
```

Here is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CgRs1YbPwrJVlvJyNHyu?p=preview)